# overflow:hidden, what am i doing wrong here

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have explicitly positioned divs, inside a parent div tag. The thing is, when I resize my browser window, i am able to scroll to the specified div position which I don't want to. I tried using overflow and it kinda does nothing other than hiding the div completely. I am clearly missing something here. How do I hide the image when I resize my browser window ? How can I solve this ?

```css
.Topics__imageContainer {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s,-webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s,-webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s,opacity .5s;
  transition: transform .5s,opacity .5s,-webkit-transform .5s;
}

.Topics__image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

.icon_wrapper_inner{   
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon_wrapper_inner">
  <div class="Topics__imageContainer" style="opacity: 1; left: 1380px;  top:268px;">
    <div class="Topics__image Topics__image--far" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:url('http://4hdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Emo-Star-Dekstop-Background-728x546.jpg');background-size:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why overflow-x?

Comment: You're scrolling horizontally, right, otherwise it would be `overflow-y`

Comment: to prevent it from overflowing, to prevent it from right scrolling.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this layout? To me it seems very hacky and forced

Comment: @adeneo I am right scrolling here

Comment: @AntonioHernández I am trying to achieve a background full of scattered images.

Comment: @Karthick if you want a background full images the why you set the top and left ??

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking: you have an inline block inside an absolutely positioned block inside a relatively positioned parent block with zero height. and no indication of what the "specified" div is. Putting the example into a page pushes the inline block past the end of the HTML block. Difficult to test.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/b4e3t9xm/3/ take look change positions. your image display scroll -y last. so tell us do you want to make  a full  background using multiple images ?

Comment: @MostafaBaezid I am adding images specifying the positions explicitly. So when I view the content on a low resolution device, I want the div to stick to the device dimensions and not scroll.

Comment: left:1380px means its gose over the widow screen 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the hidden logic in the CSS.

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding overflow:hidden inside html in bootstrap.css. Now the overflow is hidden as i resize my browser preventing it from scrolling.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```